# Use @XmlElements with multiple @XmlElement members of the same type

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Is it possible at all to use `@XmlElememts` to represent a choice between same-type parameters. Best explained with an example:

```
@XmlElements({
     @XmlElement(name="dogId", type=Long.class),
     @XmlElement(name="catId", type=Long.class)})
private Long animalId;
```

So, when I receive an `id`, I would like to know whether it's a dog or a cat.

Solution 1 would be:

```
@XmlElement
private Long dogId;

@XmlElement
private Long catId;
```

While that's an obvious solution, where I *manually* have to check that only one of them is set, in my case I really prefer the usage of the single xml field.

Would that be a good solution?

```
@XmlElements({
     @XmlElement(name="dogId", type=CatId.class),
     @XmlElement(name="catId", type=DogId.class)})
private Long animalId;

public class DogId extends BigInteger {
   ...
}

public class CatId extends BigInteger {
   ...
}
```

Is there a standard solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

or this when you want to know other properties of your animals which is bound to happen sometime

```
@XmlElements({
     @XmlElement(name="dog", type=Dog.class),
     @XmlElement(name="cat", type=Cat.class)})
private List<Animal> animals;

public class Animal {
   // common animal properties
   BigInteger id;
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    // dog specific properties
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
    // cat specific properties
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following solution:

```
@XmlElementRefs({
     @XmlElementRefs(name="dogId", namespace = "animals.com", type = JAXBElement.class),
     @XmlElementRefs(name="catId", namespace = "animals.com", type = JAXBElement.class)})
private JAXBElement<Long> animalId;
```

And then you also need an `ObjectFactory`:

```
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    private final static QName CAT_ID_QNAME = new QName("animals.com", "catId");
    private final static QName DOG_ID_QNAME = new QName("animals.com", "dogId");

    public ObjectFactory() {
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "animals.com", name = "catId", scope = AnimalsRequestXML.class)
    public JAXBElement<Long> createCatId(final Long value) {
        return new JAXBElement<>(CAT_ID_QNAME, Long.class, AnimalsRequestXML.class, value);
    }
    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "animals.com", name = "dogId", scope = AnimalsRequestXML.class)
    public JAXBElement<Long> createDogId(final Long value) {
        return new JAXBElement<>(DOG_ID_QNAME, Long.class, AnimalsRequestXML.class, value);
    }
```

This generates a `xs:choice`:

```
      <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="catId" type="xs:long"/>
        <xs:element name="dogId" type="xs:long"/>
      </xs:choice>
```